# Remember file opened in browser

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to make browser remember an audio file (up to 50MB) opened by user via input button? I am trying to create a server-less web application that can play audio files opened by users locally and it would be more user friendly if users did not have to open the same file again every time they re-open the page. When I was researching this, I only found things that are long time deprecated and only available in Chrome (Filesystem API) or seem needlessly complicated (IndexedDB). Am I missing something?

Comment: there are several ways to do this but i guess the main hint is not to store the files somewhere as they are already stored on the computer, only store the path to it, use localStorage, cookies etc. Or will those files be uploaded to be played, i have no idea how you want to achieve this or what you have tried to play local files (security issue)

Comment: @johnSmith won't he still need the user to pick up the file again? Also, local storage seems to be limited to 10mb. What about uploading the file into something like Google drive?

Comment: @johnSmith storing only path to the local file would be perfect but I was not able to figure out how to do it - if I understand correctly, this option has been removed for security reasons and you can only get fakepath that does not work after reload.

Comment: @semako I was hoping I would be able to do it without uploading - it would be so simple: the file is already on user's computer, user opened it so clearly they agree with the file being used...

Comment: @honzzz I guess it´s just not possible like this for obvious security reasons (You dont want to let websites exploit your security flaws to manipulate arbitrary files on your local computer). You have other options like doing uploads, use a database etc. or you go on sth. like Electron to built native apps

Comment: @honzzz I understand. Sadly if the user opened it once so they agree with the file being used once, but don't really agree that the website can get the same file again. The file can be updated, it is just too risky. To answer your question, I think we all agree that you can try localstorage, the limit is reasonable (~10mb). Or do a quick upload (use something like firebase or whatever, it is not so hard don't worry). The others api (indexeddb, app cache, web sql) are "unstable" I think.